# VB.net web server

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port, webserver

I've got an Arduino MEGA 2560 and I am making a smart home. IT has no WiFi or Ethernet port so I wrote a vb.net program that reads the SerialPort. But I don't know how to make a website that would show the value of a temperature sensor.

Comment: This question is much too broad to ever expect a decent answer. Check ["How to ask a good question on SO?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.....

Simple HTML page with AJAX timer....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><b>Status:</b> <span id="A1"></span></p>
<p><b>Status text:</b> <span id="A2"></span></p>
<p><b>Response:</b> <span id="A3"></span></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = xhttp.status;
      document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML = xhttp.statusText;
      document.getElementById('A3').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'TempXML.xml', true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Simple XML.....

```
<TempXML>
<DateTime>28\02\2016 22:10:00 :: </DateTime>
<body>31 &#186;C :: 87 &#186;F</body>
</TempXML>
```

Now, save the XML as 'TempXML.xml' in the SAME folder as your HTML page and then load the HTML it into you browser.... the timer in the HTML page will fire every second and read the XML, all you need to do is write\save the data coming in from your Arduino to the XML file and the HTML will update with the new data....

''''''''''''''''''''''
EDIT
''''''''''''''''''''''

Here is an example console application that writes to your XML file

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim NewTemp = New TempData

    ' Set you DateTime and Temp here
    NewTemp.DateTime = DateTime.Now
    NewTemp.fahrenheit = 80 ' Data from your Arduino 
    NewTemp.celsius = 36    ' Data from your Arduino 

    ' Create XmlWriterSettings.
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True

    Using writer As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create("<Path to your XML Temp file>\TempXML.xml", settings)
        ' Begin writing.
        writer.WriteStartDocument()
        writer.WriteStartElement("TempXML") ' Root.

        writer.WriteElementString("DateTime", NewTemp.DateTime.ToString)
        writer.WriteElementString("body", String.Format(" :: {0} °C :: {1} °F", NewTemp.celsius.ToString, NewTemp.fahrenheit.ToString))

        ' End document.
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
    End Using
End Sub

End Module


Public Class TempData

Private _DateTime As DateTime
Public Property DateTime() As DateTime
    Get
        Return _DateTime
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
        _DateTime = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _fahrenheit As Int32
Public Property fahrenheit() As Int32
    Get
        Return _fahrenheit
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Int32)
        _fahrenheit = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _celsius As Int32
Public Property celsius() As Int32
    Get
        Return _celsius
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Int32)
        _celsius = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Remember to change the Path to your XML file to suit the location on your PC in line 'Xml.XmlWriter.Create'....

Incidentally, to get the '°' degree symbol (that you see in the code above)... Position the cursor at the right location, press and hold the 'Alt' key and type 0176 and then let the 'Alt' go.....

Comment: @WtfArdDev I have updated my answer with an example Console app to write the DateTime & Temp data to your XML file, you will need to implement something similar when you receive data on the Serial port from your Arduino